# Testing if variable is iterable: Do I need to check if it is defined first?

Tags: twig

I am used to doing this in twig:

```
{% if entities is defined and entities is not null and entities|length > 0 %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Now I came across the Iterable-Test -> http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/iterable.html

Would it be sufficient to do this:

```
{% if entities is iterable %}
```

or would I still need to do this

```
{% if entities is defined and entities is iterable %}
```

To sum it up: Does the iterable check perform a "is defined" or will it throw an error?

And: Is an empty array iterable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *may not pass the variable* to the template, you need to check if this variable is defined before testing if it is iterable, as otherwise you'll get an exception that `Variable "entities" does not exist`. So the correct way is:

```
{% if entities is defined and entities is iterable %}
```

However, if you *always pass a variable* but you are not certain if it is iterable, you can simply use iterable check without testing for defined:

```
{% if entities is iterable %}
```

Otherwise, if you *always pass iterable collection in a variable* but you are not sure if it is empty or not, you don't need to check for iterability, simply use `for` loop (and `else` statement if required):

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    ...
{% else %}
    No entities to display
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using several conditions, you can use the [default filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) to give a default value to an undefined variable.

```
{% if entities|default(null) is iterable %}
```

If you want to directly iterate throught your possibly undefined `entities` variable:

```
{% for entity in entities|default([]) %}
    ...
{% else %}
    No entities to display
{% endfor %}
```